# Why does this function called: "showTree" work correctly?

Tags: c++, recursion, nodes

This is the function that I don't understand:

```
void showTree (node ​​* tree, int cont) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        showTree (tree-> right, cont + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i <cont; i ++) {
          cout << " ";
        }
        cout << tree-> data << endl;
        showTree (tree-> left, cont + 1);
    }
}
```

I do not understand:

- How do you get to the for loop if that function is always called recursively?
- How are tree items displayed if that function is always called recursively?

If someone could explain to me how this feature works I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please post the code that makes the first call to `showTree`.

Comment: Also, have you used your debugger to step-through the code to see how it works? Have you done a dry-run with a pen and square-lined paper? If not, why not?

Comment: showTree() doesn't recurse if its first argument is NULL.

Comment: 1. Recursive call would return when "end"(nullptr) is met. 2. Start from an end node would be easier to imagine, or just make a tree to test it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Indeed, that's the **base-case**. And this code should be using `nullptr`, not `NULL`. I had a flashback to the late-1990s just then!

Comment: @Dai I don't know how to debug, I use dev-c ++

Comment: @ElblackNinja You can still use a pen and paper to explore how a function works.

Comment: @Dai I have tried that, but I don't understand how the function works yet. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @ElblackNinja But that's why you should dry-run the function with a pen and paper, so you *can* understand how it works. When you do try to dry-run this function on paper, what problem are you facing? What values are you using for `tree` and `cont` when you start?

Comment: @Dai I am faced with the problem that when it finishes checking if the tree == NULL is called again but on the right, then it checks again if tree == NULL, but it is not because there are more elements "cont" is increased, and so on until it reaches when no more elements are added, then when there are no elements added, the function will be terminated, and it will never be able to reach the for.

For the tree I am using the NULL value, for "cont" the value 0.

I start when I finish putting the showTree function, assuming I have some elements of the tree.

Comment: @ElblackNinja Well yes, that's because you're using `NULL` as the initial value for `tree`. That's always never going to reach the `for` loop. **You need to re-run `showTree` but with a non-null value for `tree`** - this is why I asked for you to show the call-site of this function.

Comment: @Dai This is the call site:
```
int main ()
{
     node * tree = NULL;
     int number = 0;
     showTree (tree, number);
     return 0;
}```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you get to the for loop if that function is always called recursively?

The function returns immediately if `tree == NULL`, so it may continue onto the `for` loop.

> How are tree items displayed if that function is always called recursively?

The output is produced by the `for` loop  and the next statement, so same reasoning.

Comment: Ok, but when I finish checking if tree == NULL is going to be called again because the function must be called again. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Who is "Bellota"? So the function calls `showTree`, then goes inside the `if` if that is true, then returns, which goes back to right after the call to `showTree` where the `for` loop is.

Comment: Acorn, sorry I was using google translator, I speak Spanish. Ok, I still don't understand, but I'll try to learn how to debug in dev-c ++ to see what happens ...

Comment: Oh, so it is a translation of my nick? Cool! :) Yeah, if you can step the program in a debugger, you will very easily see how it works.

Comment: @ElblackNinja There's [es.so].

Comment: @BessieTheCow I already know it, but the ones from stackoverflow in Spanish didn't help me much.